# Error adding to .csv column numbers

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a spreadsheet currently named numberstest.csv that contains the following in column A:

```
Numbers
4
2
7
1
2
```

The goal is to add 5 to each cell under Numbers header and print the result. Using this code I run into an error listed below.

import csv

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\numberstest.csv', 'r' ) as theFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(theFile)
    for line in reader:
        print(line['Numbers'] + 5)

> File "C:/Users/Sterling/Desktop/StockProject/learningnumbers.py", line
> 6, in <module>
>     print(line['Numbers'] + float(5)) TypeError: must be str, not float
```

So to try and remedy this I did the following:

```
print(line['Numbers'] + str(5))

45
25
75
15
25
```

while this fixes the error, it does not give the desired result which is listed below:

```
9
7
12
6
7
```

I understand this clearly must be an issue with what form the cells are currently in, but I am unsure as to how to go about fixing this. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
print(line['Numbers'] + 5)
```

With

```
print(int(line['Numbers']) + 5)
```

Comment: You're amazing. I had no idea that it was that simple to simply convert the values being pulled into integers. Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: You are welcome :). Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks.